# Customize WP block gallery

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Is there any option to change the output of the WP block gallery component in Gutenberg editor?
Currently I set some images with external links (link to media attachment) and I get this result:

```
<ul class="wp-block-gallery columns-2">
    <li class="blocks-gallery-item">
        <figure>
            <a href="...">
                <img src="..." alt="" data-id="" data-link="" class="">
            </a>
            <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="blocks-gallery-item">
        <figure>
            <a href="...">
                <img src="..." alt="" data-id="" data-link="" class="">
            </a>
            <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I want to also set the title attribute for anchor element. This is the result that I want:

```
<ul class="wp-block-gallery columns-2">
    <li class="blocks-gallery-item">
        <figure>
            <a href="..." title="some title">
                <img src="..." alt="" data-id="" data-link="" class="">
            </a>
            <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="blocks-gallery-item">
        <figure>
            <a href="..." title="some title">
                <img src="..." alt="" data-id="" data-link="" class="">
            </a>
            <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `blocks.getSaveElement` filter to alter existing blocks. Take a look at this post on [Wordpress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298225/how-to-extend-the-gallery-block-in-gutenberg)